# Doubt about an inequality of supremums

Tags: set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $R^+\cup${$0$} then

$Sup(A).Sup(B)\ \ge\ Sup(AB)$ , i can't think of any counter example where the equality does not hold and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ then $a \leq Sup (A)$ and $b \leq Sup (B)$ so $ab \leq (Sup (A)) (Sup(B))$. Hence $Sup (AB) \leq (Sup (A)) (Sup(B))$.

Now let $(a_n) \subset A$ and $(b_n) \subset B$ with $a_n \to Sup(A)$ and $b_n \to Sup(B)$. Assume that $Sup (A)>0$ and $Sup (B)>0$ Then $sup(AB) \geq a_nb_n \to Sup(A)Sup(B)$ so we actually have $Sup (AB) = (Sup (A)) (Sup(B))$.  If $Sup (A)=0$ then $A=\{0\}$ and equality is obviously true. Similarly equality holds if $Sup (B)=0$.

Comment: Actually i wanted an example where equality does not hold !!!!!

Comment: @aryanbansal There is no such example. See my revised answer.